# Proof that state can be reached

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

> Prove that if the number of states in a Markov Chain is $M$, and if
>   state $j$ can be reached from state $i$, then it can be reached in $M$
>   steps or less.

To me it just seems the definition of multistep transition where $$p^m(i,j)=P(X_{n+m}=j|X_n=i)$$

But what I tried to do is

Let $i_0,i_1,\dots,i_m$ the states of Markov Chain, if exists a path from $i$ to $j$, then for $k=0,\dots,m-1$ $$P_{i_k,i_{k+1}}>0$$
such that $i_0=i$ and $i_m=j$ then any state can be reached from another in $n\leq m$ steps, where $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: It may help to think about what this effectively means. It basically means that if you started at $i$ and are trying to get to $j$, it is possible to get there without ever visiting any state twice. By contrast in a non-Markov process you might have to visit a state twice. For instance you might have $3$ states but state $3$ is only accessible from either state at time $10$.

Comment: @ConradoCosta Prove that if the number of states in a Markov Chain is $M$, and if
 state $j$ can be reached from state $i$, then it can be reached in $M$
 steps or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an informal proof; it isn't that hard to see how to formalize it, but the notation for doing so is a bit tedious.

Suppose you have a possible path $(i_0,i_1,\dots,i_n)$, where $i_0=i,i_n=j$, and $i_{k_1}=i_{k_2}=r$. Then it's possible to go directly from $r$ to $i_{k_2+1}$, and it's possible to get from $i_{k_2+1}$ to $j$. That means that $(i_0,i_1,\dots,r,i_{k_2+1},\dots,i_n)$ is a possible path which is shorter than the one you started with. Repeat this procedure until there are no identical states in your path. Conclude that the resulting path is of length at most $M$ (including the initial state).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly differently worded proof.

Consider any path of states $i_{0} = i, i_{1}, i_{2}, ... ,i_{n} = j$ such that $P_{i_{k}i_{k+1}} > 0$. If all the states in the path are distinct, then the path cannot have more than $M$ elements. On the other hand, if not all the states $i_{0}, ..., i_{n}$ are distinct then there exists a subpath consisting of distinct states (*Why?*). Hence, if a path exists, there must be one with distinct states, and thus the length of the path is at most $M$.